# Why does making width: 20% pushes one of the links away?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}

.container a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    <div class="second"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    <div class="third"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    <div class="fourth"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    <div class="fifth"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
</div>
```

First of all sorry if this question is a little bit stupid  but , what makes it push the last link out of the line even though I've made the width 20% ? I've tried setting padding to 0 , setting margin to 0 , but nothing seems to work. Is it my browser mistake for displaying it uncorrectly?

Comment: because the white space btween each other...

Answer (score 0):

Because the white space btween each other...(I gueess because `inline-block`)

You can use `display:flex` to `container` div:

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
}

.container div {
    width:20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}

.container a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    <div class="second"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    <div class="third"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    <div class="fourth"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    <div class="fifth"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
</div>
```

**Edit: use  `font-size` (instead `flex`)**

```css
    .container{
         font-size: 0;
    }

    .container div {
        display:inline-block;
        width:20%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:green;
        padding: 0;
        border-width: 0;
    }

    .container a {
     font-size: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="first"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
        <div class="second"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
        <div class="third"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
        <div class="fourth"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
        <div class="fifth"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But do you know how can i make it not override this : 
@media screen and (max-width:400px)
  

  {.container div {
   width:100%;
   padding:100px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   }}